# Email-to-Case Email on Case Record

Tags: email, case, email2case

Is there a field on the Case object that specify the Email-to-Case email address that created the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field (text) on the Case object with the following value: ***Source:EmailMessage.ToAddress***.

This will return the e-mail address that received the e-mail which led to the Case creation.

Best regards!